# Heroku + Github deployment strategies

Tags: git, node.js, deployment, heroku

I am working on a web app, hosting the source code on Github and running the app on Heroku. Everything works fine, but I have on issue I can't wrap my head around. Before the deploying my code, I run some scripts to optimize the code (minifying, concatenating files etc.). The heroku app only uses the optimized version of the app.

Basically, I have two folders: `dev` and `production`. `Dev` contains the source code I write, `production` is produced by my build scripts (I use grunt and requirejs). Currently, both folders are in my Git repository and both are pushed to Github and Heroku. What I'd rather like is to only have `dev` on Github and only `production` on Heroku. 
I read some articles how to setup different branches for Heroku, as [described in this blog](http://suitmymind.com/blog/2009/06/02/deploying-multiple-environments-on-heroku-while-still-hosting-code-on-github/). Could I setup a production branch and only have the `production` folder in there while keeping the `dev` folder to my master branch? Or would I need separate repositories?

Has anyone tried something similar? I would assume that this is not something out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to simply consider using the heroku `.slugignore` file (ref https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler).

This file would allow you remove the `dev` folder from the package that heroku deploys to each server instance, while allowing you to keep all your code in the same repository.

The root of the problem is thinking about the deployment strategy as one where you upload final bits to your server, where *the bits are an artefact of building your repository*. In such cases, builds are usually stored and archived separately from the source.

Heroku's model is slightly different from this in that it assumes *your repository is the artefact to deploy*. The difference is slight, but in your case, it just means that you need to commit to your repository the bits you want heroku to serve.

Another way of thinking about it is that you could do without your `production` folder, and as part of starting your server, the script would be run to generate the `production` folder files. This would allow you to remove the `production` folder, and keep your repository clean at the cost of running this process on every start of your server. This may prove to be prohibitively expensive and undesirable (there are limits to how long Heroku will wait for a server to startup before it gives up on it), but hopefully helps in providing some clarity around the Heroku and git relationship.

Comment: This is what I am doing now ... I created my own custom buildpack (see https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt) which uses Grunt to build the production folder on every deploy. It works fine and I can keep all the production stuff out of the git repo.

Comment: Another feature I've used in the standard buildpack is supported via NPM. You can add a `"postinstall"` script to your `package.json` and run arbitrary code this way.

https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html

Answer (score 5):

This situation is a bit unusual. But here are some ideas:

- I use a process that's similar to the one in the article you referenced.
- I'd create only a single app as your saying. I'd create it starting a new git repository in your `dev` folder.
- I'd then recommend a deployment strategy similar to the one described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8058194/267025 . I've adapted it below:

Create a `rake` file with two tasks in it: `rake deploy:production` and `rake deploy:postprocess_files`. Those tasks might look something like this:

```
namespace :deploy do

  task :production do
    puts "turn on 'maintenance page' on heroku"
    system "heroku maintenance:on"

    puts "deploying to production"
    system "git push heroku-prod master"

    puts "post processing files..."
    system "heroku run rake production:postprocess_files"

    puts "take off maintenance page"
    system "heroku maintenance:off"

    puts "done"
  end 

  task :postprocess_files do
    puts "run postprocessing of files on heroku"
    ... add commands here to post process the files.
  end 
end
```

Then deploy to production using `rake deploy:production` rather than pushing using git directly. The rake file will then:

1. set the maintenance page,
2. push to production,
3. do your post processing of files,
4. take down the maintenance page.

Note that the second rake task in your file has the commands to do the post processing on your files and is invoked to run *on heroku* by the first rake task.

As an alternative, it's possible you may be able to extend the assets:precompile task that Heroku runs as part of each deploy. That's essentially what you're doing anyway -- preparing assets for deployment to production.

Comment: I don't think this would work. In the documentation about One-off processes (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps) it says "Each dyno has its own ephemeral filesystem, not shared with any other dyno, that is discarded as soon as you disconnect.". This would work fine for database scripts etc. but not for something that modifies the filesystem. Or am I missing something? Also, why is my situation unsual?

Comment: I believe you may be correct -- also, I realized after I wrote this that you're deploying node.js code and not rails code.

Comment: My comment about your situation being unusual was made based on my assuming you were deploying rails code. I'm less familiar with node.js on heroku so that may not be the case.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit confusing because:

- your `dev` and `production` represent **environments**, and are directories with *generated* content:
  They shouldn't be in a VCS, but automatically produced by a script which would recognize the environment in which it is running, and create the right directory accordingly.
- the `dev` and `production` mentioned in the article you are referring to "[Deploying multiple environments on Heroku (while still hosting code on Github)](http://suitmymind.com/blog/2009/06/02/deploying-multiple-environments-on-heroku-while-still-hosting-code-on-github/)" represent **promotion stages**, and are *branches*.

Using branches is good, only for isolating code variations (in said branches), not for storing release generated code.
Your particular release management issue (ie generating the right delivery) should be managed by a script (which can be version-controlled alongside your code), and use as a hook, for instance, to generate and deploy the right set of codes at the right place.

Comment: 'dev' does not contain generated content, that's the source code I write in there. 'production' is the same but with the optimized files. I know the difference to branches. The issue I have is with Heroku deployment being based on Git repositories. I can only deploy what's in the repository. I can not separate between what's being pushed to Github and what's being pushed to Heroku (if not using branches).

Answer (score 2):

I personally love this solution: https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt
And take a look at this too: https://medium.com/the-javascript-collection/how-to-deploy-a-grunt-project-on-heroku-c227cb1ddc56

It is honestly one of the cleanest way.

Comment: Nice! This is actually my own project. Really glad others find it as useful as I do.