# Pushing to bitbucket and deploying to heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku, playframework, bitbucket, playframework-2.1

I have Play! application in Bitbucket. I have my local repo linked to both Bitbucket and Heroku and everything works fine (whenever I push to **heroku master**, the application re-builds and I can see the changes online). Now, I want only to push to bitbucket and deploy to Heroku, i.e. I want to push to Bitbucket, and my Heroku app to pick the changes from Bitbucket and rebuilds the app. The reason I want this is because Bitbucket now offers online code editing and I do not always have *Git* or *Heroku Toolbelt* installed in the systems I work. It will also be nice to manage a single repo.

I know that Heroku maintains it's own git system and from Heroku's *Settings* tab, I can see following info -

```
Region: United States
Stack: Cedar
Framework: Play 2.x - Scala
Git URL: git@heroku.com:xyz-abc.git
Repo size: 139 MB
Slug size: 117 MB of 200 MB
```

Also, I have changed the `GitHub Repo` settings in Heroku to `git@bitbucket.org:user-xyz/xyz-abc.git`. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240227/deploying-to-heroku-using-git-on-bitbucket) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175923/heroku-github-deployment-strategies) SO issues  and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code) Heroku documentation related to my requirement, but couldn't make it work. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could have used [Bitbucket Services](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Managing+Bitbucket+Services;jsessionid=6879651E3D395506FB11B5AB88BF916C); unfortunately, there is none for Github. Maybe you could try to [build one and submit to Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Writing+Brokers+for+Bitbucket).

Answer (score 0):

The Github Repo setting in Heroku simply displays the commit diffs in the activity log - there's a note to that effect just in the Github repo text

```
Link your app to a GitHub repository to see commit diffs in the activity log.
```

It doesn't provide any other functionality at present.

I'm not familiar with Play myself, but with Rails and the add Codeship.io (and others I imagine) you can do continuous deployment where you push to github/bitbucket and that then uses a webhook to trigger codeship to pick up your code, test it and then deploy it to Heroku. I'm sure there are Play hosted testing services out there which may help.