# How can I clear rails cache after deploy to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, caching, deployment

I applied cache to my heroku rails app and it works well. 
But everytime I deploy to heroku, I also want to clear cache automatically.

so I googled and I found this.

```
task :after_deploy, :env, :branch do |t, args|
  puts "Deployment Complete"
  puts "Cleaning all cache...."
  FileUtils.cd Rails.root do
    sh %{heroku run console}
    sh %{Rails.cache.clear}
  end
end
```

but when I raked this script, it just show the heroku console command line but the Rails.cache.clear command does not typed. (I guess that is because heroku console is interactive)

and

```
system "heroku console Rails.cache.clear"
```

doesn't work for cedar apps.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear Memcached on Heroku Deploy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732985/clear-memcached-on-heroku-deploy)

Answer (score 43):

Rails has a built in rake task:

```
rake tmp:clear
```

Answer (score 40):

The following should work on cedar:

```
heroku run console
```

..then wait 5 seconds for heroku console to boot

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

Then you should see the cache clear, and you can quit console. Remember you might have to refresh a few times because your local machine will often cache assets and such in your browser until it makes a fresh request.

If it happens to be assets that you're caching though, you don't need to go through a manual clear every time you push, you just need to have the asset pipeline set up and make sure all your js/css(less/sass)/static images are being compiled with hashes at the end of their filenames.

Comment: but as you know, the script what I wrote is rake script. I know that the command 'heroku run console' returns after 5 seconds and I can type 'Rails.cache.clear'. but I want to automate it with my rake script everytime I deploy to heroku.

Comment: follow this pattern http://michaeldwan.com/writings/customize-your-heroku-deployment.html and then add an :after_deploy hook that just calls Rails.cache.clear.

Comment: Yes I saw that pattern. but I don't know how can I connect to heroku console and call Rails.cache.clear.

Answer (score 32):

You should be able to create a cache clearing rake task that looks something like this:

```
namespace :cache do
  desc "Clears Rails cache"
  task :clear => :environment do
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
end
```

and invoke it directly in one command that you can use in your post deploy hook - like so:

```
heroku run rake cache:clear
```

Answer (score 15):

Ruby on Rails has a magical ENV variable called 'RAILS_CACHE_ID'.  I set this to the git commit id whenever I deploy: `heroku config:set RAILS_CACHE_ID=$CIRCLE_SHA1`

Comment: TIL `RAILS_CACHE_ID` is a thing. Very cool. Adjusted for those of us not using circle ci: `heroku config:set RAILS_CACHE_ID=`git rev-parse HEAD``

Answer (score 4):

If you want to simply run a rake task after deploy, I would recommend checking out:

https://github.com/gunpowderlabs/buildpack-ruby-rake-deploy-tasks

We've been using it in production for over 6 months and it's been rock solid.

First, add the buildpack AFTER you already have the Ruby buildpack set. This should happen after your first deploy to the server

`heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/gunpowderlabs/buildpack-ruby-rake-deploy-tasks`

Second, set an environment variable called `DEPLOY_TASKS` with just the names of the rake tasks you want to run separated by spaces.

`heroku config:set DEPLOY_TASKS='cache:clear`

Comment: This is the best approach and should be marked as accepted answer. This solution does not imply manual action nor does it imply to modify the project itself.

Comment: As a note, this has been deprecated in favour of Heroku's "Release Phase" functionality

Answer (score 0):

heroku run rake tmp:cache:clear

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#tmp

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't currently support a pipeline of actions to occur after deployment. You'll need something like Codeship or TravisCI to create a recipe of steps that happen during deployment

Disclosure: I am a customer of Codeship.

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku has a `release` phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase), which means you can put any deploy-time tasks inside your `Procfile`:

```
release: bundle exec rake tmp:clear
```

You might want to set up your own custom rake task to encapsulate any other tasks that need to happen at deploy, e.g.: `db:migrate` and so forth. Keep in mind that if the task fails for any reason, Heroku will halt the deploy and the previously deployed version of the code will remain active.