# Heroku Rails: Invalidate cache for /public/*.html on deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, static, http-headers

I have a few raw .html files in /public that are still being cached after I edit and deploy them. The goal is not to have to ask clients to clear their cache when the files change (often).

My production.rb contains this:

```
# Use a different cache store in production
# pks: recommended by heroku
config.cache_store = :dalli_store

# For Rack::Cache on heroku
# Modify your config/environments/production.rb environment file to specify
# the appropriate storage backends for Rails’ built-in Rack::Cache integration.
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
    :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
    :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
    :allow_reload => false
}
# To allow your application to properly serve, invalidate and refresh static assets 
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=0" # 2592000" # max-age=0 to to force revalidate
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

[image: HTTP Headers for static html asset]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to just create a script that you run whenever you want to deploy that calls whatever command you use to deploy and then uses the commands listed within the following post ([How can I clear rails cache after deploy to heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028088/how-can-i-clear-rails-cache-after-deploy-to-heroku))