# Rails.cache.clear fails with undefined method `clear' for nil:NilClass when running in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

Upon following the [instructions to create a rake task to clear the cache,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812101/773210) when running that rake task:

```
namespace :cache do
  desc "Clears Rails cache"
  task :clear do
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
end
```

and running that rake task with:

```
rake cache:clear
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `clear' for nil:NilClass
```

When running Rails.cache.clear from the rails console, it successfully clears the cache without an error.  Why is cache nil on the Rails object in the rake task, but not in the rails console?

Note: I am using dalli and memcache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer **Why is => :environment needed?**

`:environment` is a task defined by rails.
When you need to interact with your application models, perform database queries and so on, your custom task should depend on the `environment` task, as it will load your rails application code.

`Rails.cache` will return nil if your application is not loaded.
Hence, the error `undefined method 'clear' for nil:NilClass`

You need to run `environment` task before your custom `clear` task.

```
namespace :cache do
  desc "Clears Rails cache"
  task :clear => :environment do  ## This will run environment task first and then clear task
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I was missing => :environment after :clear

The below works:

```
namespace :cache do
  desc "Clears Rails cache"
  task :clear => :environment do
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
end
```

Why is => :environment needed?