# Rails clear cache on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

How can I clear the cache on Heroku?

I've tried `heroku run rails c` + `Rails.cache.clear` and receive the following error

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /app/tmp/cache/
```

I also tried `heroku run rake tmp:clear` (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028088/how-can-i-clear-rails-cache-after-deploy-to-heroku) post). The task runs but when I go back into the console and run `Rails.cache`, nothing has changed.

How can I clear the cache?

Comment: Which cache do you want to clear? Do you have any cache enabled?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti the application cache (so all cache, I think?). I'm getting some funky behavior after pushing new code and think flushing it will help.

Comment: Try `heroku run console` instead of `heroku run rails c`

Comment: What is the funky behavior. May be the issue is not related to the caching...

Comment: @SimoneCarletti irregardless of the funky behavior I'd like to be able to flush the application cache

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri same behvaior

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this? (This works with `Celadon Cedar` with the `Heroku Toolbelt package` at least)

```
heroku run --app YOUR_APP_NAME rails runner Rails.cache.clear
```

#### Update

If the above does not work, try running:

```
heroku run rake tmp:create
heroku run rake tmp:clear
```

Comment: yeh, same result `No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /app/tmp/cache/ (Errno::ENOENT)`

Comment: @user2954587 please try the updated answer and let me know if that works!

Comment: also, did you try: `heroku run rake cache:clear` command directly? rather from heroku console?