# Django Heroku Clear Cache on deploy

Tags: django, heroku, redis

I'm using a Redis cache (django-redis) for my Django app hosted on Heroku. To be more specific (though I don't think it's relevant to the probable solution), I'm using the Redis Cloud add-on.

How do I clear the cache upon deploy? I'm looking for an answer similar to [Clear Memcached on Heroku Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732985/clear-memcached-on-heroku-deploy), except for Django, not Rails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out how to make this work (combination of MagnusGraviti's answer and some help from heroku IRC).

**Step 1:**

Create a custom command to clear cache. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/ or install django-clear-cache https://github.com/rdegges/django-clear-cache.

**Step 2:**

Create a script (for example, scripts/web) to place the command in [from the project root level]. For example, I prepended my Procfile web command with `python manage.py clearcache &&` as below:

**scripts/web**

```
python manage.py clearcache && gunicorn myapp.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 5 --preload
```

**Step 3:**

Then, you need to set the script to executable. On my OSX machine, the command was just:

```
chmod a+x scripts/web
```

**Step 4:**

Modify the Procfile to run script instead of a command:

```
web: scripts/web
```

That's it!

Comment: Nice! :-) Congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

You have next options:

- I always thought it was possible (and foreman locally worked for me with &&. Write your command `python manage.py clear_cache` and use it before launching server in  `Procfile`:

`web: python manage.py clear_cache && gunicorn...`

- If you use CircleCI you can edit your `circle.yml` file to clear cache after deployment
- If you wrote `fabfile` you can include `python manage.py clear_cache` after deployment.

**clear_cache command example:**

`

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.cache import cache


class Command(BaseCommand):
    """
    Command to clear cache
    """
    help = "Clear cache"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        cache.clear()
```

Comment: This answer seems promising, except I'm unable to get foreman to recognize two commands in one line (the "web: python manage.py clearcache && ..." solution). How do I account for this?

Comment: I just now made Procfile with `web: python manage.py clear_cache && gunicorn myapp.wsgi` and made `foreman start`. It works. What error foreman gives you?

Comment: mine's a little different. "web: python manage.py clearcache && newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn doorstep.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 5 --preload" gives me the error " manage.py: error: no such option: -b"

Comment: Does this set of commands launch without foreman successfully?

Comment: python manage.py clearcache works by itself. and the procfile without the "python manage.py clearcache && ..." worked

Comment: Oh, then it seems to be not an option to use &&. Try writing your own fabfile for deploy. It is not difficult to do and you'll be able to make database migration, clear cache etc.

Comment: figured out how to complete the puzzle from heroku irc. Posted my answer below